# dplyr gives me different answers depending on how I select columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I may be having trouble understanding some of the basics of dplyr, but it appears that R behaves very differently depending on whether you subset columns as one column data frames or as traditional vectors. Here is an example:

```
mtcarsdf<-tbl_df(mtcars)

example<-function(x,y) {
  df<-tbl_df(data.frame(x,y))
  df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(total=sum(y))
}
#subsetting to cyl this way gives integer vector
example(mtcars$gear,mtcarsdf$cyl)
# 3 112
# 4 56
# 5 30

#subsetting this way gives a one column data table
example(mtcars$gear,mtcarsdf[,"cyl"])
# 3 198
# 4 198
# 5 198
all(mtcarsdf$cyl==mtcarsdf[,"cyl"])
# TRUE
```

Since my inputs are technically equal the fact that I am getting different outputs tells me I am misunderstanding how the two objects behave. Could someone please enlighten me on how to improve the example function so that it can handle different objects more robustly?

Thanks

Comment: The only thing I can think of is setting the column names in your `example()` function. Replace `df <- tbl_df(data.frame(x, y))` with `df <- tbl_df(setNames(data.frame(x, y), c("x", "y")))` and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: The problem seems to be that `tbl_df` does not have `drop=TRUE` like a `data.frame` does, so `mtcarsdf[,"cyl"]` is not a vector but a `tbl_df` itself.

Comment: @Frank, I was just going to mention the same thing and suggest using `[[` instead :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto Yeah, that's what they should use. I'll leave it to you or someone else to post an answer, since I can't find (an no longer want to dig for) documentation of dplyr's nonstandard behavior with `[`. (It tells me `drop ignored` when I try to switch it to true!)

Comment: I think the relevant help section is `?tbl_df`: "**Methods**: `[` Never simplifies (drops), so always returns data.frame"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the items that you are comparing with `==` are not really the same. This could be identified using `all.equal` instead of `==`:

```
all.equal(mtcarsdf$cyl, mtcarsdf[, "cyl"])
## [1] "Modes: numeric, list"                           
## [2] "Lengths: 32, 1"                                 
## [3] "names for current but not for target"           
## [4] "Attributes: < target is NULL, current is list >"
## [5] "target is numeric, current is tbl_df"
```

With that in mind, you should be able to get the behavior you want by using `[[` to extract the column instead of `[`.

```
mtcarsdf <- tbl_df(mtcars)

example<-function(x,y) {
  df<-tbl_df(data.frame(x,y))
  df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(total=sum(y))
}

example(mtcars$gear, mtcarsdf[["cyl"]])
```

However, a safer approach might be to integrate the renaming of the columns as part of your function, like this:

```
example2 <- function(x, y) {
  df <- tbl_df(setNames(data.frame(x, y), c("x", "y")))
  df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(total = sum(y))
}
```

Then, any of the following should give you the same results.

```
example2(mtcars$gear, mtcarsdf$cyl)
example2(mtcars$gear, mtcarsdf[["cyl"]])
example2(mtcars$gear, mtcarsdf[, "cyl"])
```